# How to test the validity of XML against an XML Schema in ActionScript?

Tags: xml, apache-flex, validation, actionscript, schema

I don't need to parse the XML, or to decode it into an ActionScript object -- I'm only interested in loading both XSD and XML and tell whether the latter is legal XML according to the document definition in the former.

Comment: I'm also after just a quick thing that can tell me "Yes its valid" or "No its invalid".. I dont need it to convert it to an object or anything. Everywhere keeps pointing me to the misprintt blog which is not helpful in the slightest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Flex has runtime xml schema support in its mx.rpc.xml package which are hidden from the livedocs.  Check out this [post](http://blog.misprintt.net/?p=192), you can find much more info there.

Comment: Thanks -- I already found that post and it seems that you're right: there's no official, documented way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

There is no built in support for DTD/Schema validation and I'm not aware about any third party implementation, so I guess that you will have to rely on the server side for that.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find anything either, but I'd recommend Relax NG over a DTD (if you have the option). It's much cleaner and more flexible.

Comment: Thanks. I don't have any experience with RELAX NG, and the XML Schema is already written -- so I think I'll stick to that.